# invisible functions description in own package

Tags: r

I've just created my first package and I have some problems with description. I was trying to use vignette with code `usethis::use_vignette("introduction")` and it creates introduction to package and to included functions. To see it I pressed "knit" button and it works, look nice etc.. I also create new R script and use library('mypackage') and all function work, but I have no idea how can I see my vignette (description of package and functions). For example in packages like `ggplot2` or `graphics` you can just put `??ggplot2, ??graphics` to just see description of package. But putting `??mypackage` I see in R help 'No results found'. How can I see this created vignette not in model building tools, but in new script which refers to my package.

Answer (score 1):

RStudio's build and reload does not build vignettes by default.  You'll need to use `devtools::build()` to ensure vignettes are built.    If you are using Github to install the package use `devtools::install_github("package", build_vignettes = TRUE)`

Comment: Okey I see now that my vignette was created. But how can I see it ? '??mypackage' does not seems to work.

Comment: Check out the vignette() function

Comment: Yea, but when i put vignette() and I get all vignettes of my installed packages, I don't have mine. 

vignette("introduction",package="mypackage") also not working

Comment: How are you actually installing the package - from github?

Comment: No, I'm creating my own in R studio

Comment: Try using install() with the argument build_vignettes = TRUE

Comment: It's very weird but it's still not creating that vignette